# Iterating over properties and use each one in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I am trying to simplify my code a bit by iterating over the columns in a table and use each column to map to a value instead of having multiple lines of code with a single different value.
So going from this:

```
foreach(var n in groupedResults){
    SetCellForData("Column1", n.Sum(x => x.ColumnName1FromTable));
    SetCellForData("Column2", n.Sum(x => x.ColumnName2FromTable));
    ...
    SetCellForData("Column10", n.Sum(x => x.ColumnName10FromTable));
}
```

To something like this:

```
var columnProperties = typeof(TableClass).GetProperties().Select(t => t);
foreach(var n in groupedResults){
    foreach(var columnProperty in columnProperties ){
        SetCellForData(columnProperty.Name, n.Sum(x => x.????);
    }
}
```

Where the ???? part uses the columnProperty to Sum the column in the n grouped result.

Comment: This is actually very complex. If you have 10 properties, frankly you'd be better off keeping your original code. If you have 100, maybe it is worth considering

Comment: @MarcGravell:Hi Marc, any example how it can be done?

Comment: arekzyla shows an example using expression trees; personally I'd tend to add a "per T, per property-name" cache to that, to avoid excessive IL emit, but... the code shown will work (assuming the result is made more LINQ-friendly, for example `Func<T,int>` or `Func<T,decimal>`, etc)

Comment: @arekzyla How come you removed your answer? I was going to mark it as the correct one since it did what I asked. If you do not add the answer then I will create my own answer using the code you posted before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since arekzyla decided to delete his answer before I could confirm that it was what I needed then I have decided to answer my own question with arekzyla's answer.

This method creates the function:

```
private static Func<T, U> GetPropertyFunc<T, U>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, U>>(body, parameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

This code iterates over the properties in the database type and creates a function for each of them returning an integer.

```
var columnProperties = typeof(DatabaseType).GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            .Select(t => new { t.Name, GetPropertyFunc = GetPropertyFunc<DatabaseType, int>(t.Name) })
            .ToList();
```

Then we iterate over some grouped list:

```
foreach (var n in groupedList)
{
    foreach (var property in columnProperties)
    {
        var sumOfElementsInGrouping = n.Sum(x => property.GetPropertyFunc(x));
    }   
}
```

Then we have the sum of the specific column based on the property.